# Mongoose – find by Double field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to find by Double in my Mongoose schema. I have the code like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('mongoose-double')(mongoose);
var SchemaTypes = mongoose.Schema.Types;

var tourSchema = mongoose.Schema({
...
  priceUsd: {
    type: SchemaTypes.Double
  },
...
});

var Tour = mongoose.model('Tour', tourSchema);
```

and want to find by `priceUsd`, but tried everything, nothing works. Let's say this (most expected for me way) doesn't:

```
Tour.find({priceUsd: {$gt: 10}}, callback);
```

Any suggestions how to do that properly?

Comment: Can you update your question to include a sample doc you expect the query to return?

Comment: hm, some kind of doc which can e converted to JSON like {... priceUsd: 12.13, ...}

Comment: 12.13 < 1000 so that doc wouldn't be returned.

Comment: haha, thanks, but that's just a sample, I mean I've tried the `$gt: 1` for example as well

Comment: We really need to see an specific example of a document in your collection that's not being returned as expected as it works fine when I try it.